# How to parse a function with a variable argument number?

Tags: java, javacc

Until now my parser is able to parse functions with a known parameter number using expressions such as this

`<FUNCTION><OPENPAR> son=expression() <COMMA> son1=expression() <CLOSEPAR>`

Also, optional parameters can also easily be handled

`<FUNCTION><OPENPAR> son=expression() <COMMA> son1=expression() [<COMMA> son2=expression()] <CLOSEPAR>`

However, I haven't been able to find documentation regarding the possibility of capturing an unknown number of parameters. My guess is something like this

`<FUNCTION><OPENPAR> son=expression() <COMMA> son1=expression() [<COMMA> son2=expression()]+ <CLOSEPAR>`

But in this case I don't know how to capture of these multiple parameters should be done.

Any ideas or examples? (or if anyone knows that this is impossible)

Comment: Did you read the documentation of the grammar file at https://javacc.org/javaccgrm ?  Have you read any of the tutorials listed in the FAQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say at least one parameter is required. Then, you would need something like:

```
private X myFunction():
{
  X result = new X();
}
{

  <FUNCTION>
    <OPENPAR> 
                  son=expression() { result.params.add(son); }
       (  <COMMA> son=expression() { result.params.add(son); } )*
    <CLOSEPAR>
    { return result; }
}
```

To sum up, my approach is to:

1. Create result Java class X and use it as you would in plain Java.
2. Initialize what's required at the beginning.
3. Return filled object.

If you still need working example, you may find [this](https://github.com/kangur85/jdfm/blob/master/src/eu/kaszkowiak/jdfm/parser/DfmParser.jj) useful.